# Chrome app content security policy issue

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to build a chrome app that embeds Youtube content but facing this error while using some scripts :
"*Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*"

I've followed the documentation as long i tried to look around the web and found out i needed to loosen the CSP. Here is my manifest.json

```
{    
    ...

    "permissions": ["https://*.youtube.com"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.youtube.com; object-src 'self'"

}
```

but i still have the same error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [cannot override CSP for apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#but). The reference you found was for extensions.

Your options are limited to [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#webview) embedding and [sandboxing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#sandboxing).